# Generate Hibernate Envers primary key manually and jpa as well

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

My project is migrating from Grails to Java so I have exisiting Audit data in a single table pushed by Grails Audit plugin, now I am using Java envers for Auditing in java. I have below doubts:

-> If i want to push data from single table to different Audit tables(in Java) manually, how can i generate Primary key of revision table for history data manually which will not collide with primary key generated from Java annotation?
As for new entries I am generating primary key like below:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "ID") @NotNull
    private Long revisionId;
```

-> Any other way to push data from single audit table to segregated Audit tables(In java) instead of doing it manually?

Please let me know about this.

Thanks.

Comment: What dialect are you using?

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Answer (score 0):

Envers should be creating sequence named **REVISION_LISTENER** on Oracle.

Therefore you should be able to use Oracle's syntax `SELECT REVISION_LISTENER.NEXTVAL` in order to get the next sequence value and use that in the `REV` field both in your audit table and the revision entity info table too.

This only applies to `DefaultAuditStrategy`.

If you intend to use the `ValidityAuditStrategy`, there are other fields which you'll have to understand the internals of Envers in order to be able to populate the relevant fields.  If you are using this strategy, let me know and I'll add more details that are specific to it, but its very complex and quite tedious.

Comment: Thanks a lot Naros..I have not defined any audit strategy so that means i can use your solution , i will check and let you know the results..